# Notepad++ regex / Excel macro to delete specific range of lines

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I have data like follows:

> 1. gooddata
> 2. gooddata
> 3. gooddata
>
> FF
>
> randomdata
>
> irrelevantdata
>
> ---
>
> headers
>
> ---
>
> 4. gooddata
> 5. gooddata
> 6. gooddata
>
> FF

and it goes on repeatedly for over thousands of lines. I have two proposed solution ideas

**Notepad++**

Create a regex to Find x criteria and delete subsequent of y number of lines

or

**VBA**

Find "FF" and delete everything until "---". find next "FF" and delete everything until next "---" .

So the output intended be like:

> 1. gooddata
> 2. gooddata
> 3. gooddata
> 4. gooddata
> 5. gooddata
> 6. gooddata

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a regular expression replace in Notepad++.

```
Find : FF.*?\-\-\-
Replace with: (Blank Text)
Search Mode: Regular Expression
Check . Match New Lines checkbox
```

Comment: Thanks! with some modification it works. It'd be great if it doesnt leave a new line in between the "gooddata" but i guess I could use some tricks to just remove the blank lines. Thank you very much sir.

Comment: Just in case anyone wondering how to remove empty line Edit> Line Operation > Remove blank lines. Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend you to install TextFX plugin for Notepad++, which will help you to handle lots of text operations including blank line removal.